# Searching for latest Email sent to an address gives me the wrong date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api

I'm running an audit across all of the company email mailboxes to see which ones have received any recent mail, I can run this code on my email and it gives me the correct date, when I run it on an alias is gives me the wrong date and I don't know why.

My code is

```
var email = steven@email.com
function lastEmailTo(email) {
  var threads = GmailApp.search('to:' + email, 0, 1);
  if (threads.length > 0) {
    var lastThread = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
    var messages = lastThread.getDate();
    return "last email received: " + messages;
  } else {
    return "No emails sent to this address";
  }
}
```

The result returned is Tue Jul 27 12:22:11 GMT+01:00 2021

The Actual result according to the mail log in the Google Console is
Mar 20, 2024, 3:51:31 PM

which is very much different, any advice on why this might happen would be very much appreciated, thank you

Comment: What do you mean when you say `When I input the email address it should give me the correct date back` how  do you input the email  address?  Please provide a [mcve] and please read the link for figure how to make one.  It should be something that allows us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your code works for me.  So I cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: The code does bring back a date it's just the wrong date, it's bringing back one years ago when the latest email was from that day, I just wanted to know why it's returning a the wrong date, thank you

Comment: I took your code and ran it on my account and it returns the correct value.  So we cannot reproduce the problem because you are unable to provide a [mcve]

Comment: I've added the full function that I used thank you